# programmatically calling functions from type library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw, typelib

I need to import a type library (it's actually an .exe that gives access to a COM interface implementation).

The thing is that i want to do that but with the MinGW compiler and not VSC++.
There are many topics and threads on SO that explain the difference between the two #import directives, but the main idea is that we can't import type libraries with the MinGW import.

So why not try to load the type library programmatically at runtime using the
[LoadTypeLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221027.aspx) function and the ITypeLib interface.

Except that ITypeLib is rather used to describe the objects stored in the type library.

Now i have run on my .exe code similar to the one in this link [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/tlb/)
to retrieve information about my .exe's methods and it shows what i expected (the same information i found in the generated .tlh with vc++)

1. Is there a way to call directly the library's functions ?? If yes :
2. Should I use the IDispatch::Invoke method ?
3. Is there a necessity for binding functions in the type library or mapping the class members (using ITypeComp::Bind) ?
4. Is there any way to convert the generated .tlh and .tli with vc++ into a normal .h & .cpp file and be able to use it with mingw compiler?

Thank you for your precisions !

Comment: It just cruel and unusual punishment to have to write IDispatch::Invoke().  The MSVC++ #import directive is just a code generator, converting the type library content to C++ code.  Mingw supports all the wrapper classes that the generated .tli and .tlh files need.  So just use them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment hans. 
I ended up writing a c-wrapper and compiling it (as a dll) on vc++ then calling the dll from mingw main and it works !
Would be happy to post my solution (specific code) if anyone is facing the same problem.
Cheers